# django adding quotes on subsequent submits

Tags: django

Here's the goal:  when the user submits the form, use one view to send the submitted data to the database, then redirect back to the form, but with the data pre-populated.  This is *mostly* working, but something about my implementation is wrapping extra quotes around the string.  For now, I'm just using a super-simple form, btw.  I enter `Billy`, and the pre-pop is: `"Billy"`, if I click submit again, it comes back as: `"\"Billy\""`, then `"\"\\\"Billy\\\"\""`, and so on (as far as I have tested, anyways.

relevant views are:

```
def editUsers(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = usersForm(request.POST)
        # check whether it's valid:
        # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
        # redirect to a new URL:
        name = json.dumps(form.data['user_name'])
        request.session['editUserName'] = name

        # call out to limboLogic.py to update values

        test = name
        return redirect('../users')
    # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
    else:
        return redirect('../users')

from .forms import *

def users(request):
    form = None

    if 'editUserName' not in request.session:
        # create a blank form
        form = usersForm()
    else:
        # form = equipmentForm(initial='jim') - used to make sure I was branching the if/else correctly
        form = usersForm(initial={'user_name':request.session['editUserName']}, auto_id=False) #limboLogic.GetUserInfo(name))
    return render(request, 'limboHtml/UserManagement.html', {'form': form})
```

form is simply:

```
class usersForm(forms.Form):
    user_name = forms.CharField(label='New User\'s  name', max_length=100)
```

and the template is:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
 <div class="row">
    <p>This is the user management page</p><br>
    <form action="/edit/users.html" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        <input type="submit" value="OK">
    </form>
    <br><p class="bold">This is below the form</p>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I can't quite say what the intracies are here, but the problem involves the fact that I was using a json class.  I used [this site](https://ultimatedjango.com/learn-django/lessons/understanding-forms/) as a guide and managed to fix the problem.  note that the key aspect is inside the second if:

`name = form.cleaned_data['user_name']` works fine,

`name = json.dumps(form.data['user_name'])` does not

the whole function as it now stands:

```
def editUsers(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = usersForm(request.POST)
        # check whether it's valid:
        # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
        # redirect to a new URL:
        if form.is_valid():
            name = form.cleaned_data['user_name']
            # name = json.dumps(form.data['user_name'])
            request.session['editUserName'] = name

            # call out to limboLogic.py to update values

            test = name
            return redirect('../users')
    # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
    return redirect('../users')
```